# Configured Public/Private Key on CentOS6 - Still letting me connect without Private Key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have a VPS with CentOS 6.  I've noticed a lot of login attempts via SSH, so I want to lock it down with key based authentication.  Here is what I have done so far....

Ran the following on my client machine (OSX)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Did this with default settings (no passphrase, default names, etc)

Set the following permissions on my client

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

copied my public key to the root of my userfolder on my VPS using the following command (fake name/ip)

```
scp id_rsa.pub fakeuser@255.255.255.255:/home/fakeuser/id_rsa.pub
```

Here I noticed that I did NOT have an authorized_keys file within my .ssh.  So I used touch to create it.  Then I used CAT to copy the contents of the .pub into the authorized_keys file

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and set the appropriate permissions on .ssh and authorized_keys

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config I uncommented the following

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I then restarted sshd

```
service sshd restart
```

From what I read, this is all I should have to do to enable public key authentication.  However, when I attempt to SSH without supplying -i privatekey, I am allowed in from all devices.

Comment: Just as a followup... I tried to copy the key using ssh-copy-id root@IPADDRESS and it shows 1 key was copied.  I can log in without needing to supply my password, however from other devices that do not have the private key, I can connect as well.

Comment: Be aware that these login attempts you're seeing are all just automated bots scanning through the entire internet looking for easy to capture, vulnerable servers. The only way to protect against that is not having an SSH server at all, or at least not on port 22. If you don't use default passwords that are found in a list, you should be pretty safe though (`pi:raspberry` anyone?) - but it's definitely better to not allow passwords at all for SSH.

Answer (score 2):

If a client key is in the default location `~/.ssh/id_$alg` it is used automatically unless you use `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` (or the equivalent config file entry) to disable it. If you are able to connect from a client that does not have a copy of the privatekey *and* without specifying a password, then the authentication on your server is not set correctly. If you want to use *only* privatekey->publickey authentication, configure `PasswordAuthentication no` .

PS: `anything >>file` (and `anything >file` also) creates the file if it doesn't exist, you don't need to `touch` it. And the default remote dir for `scp` is your homedir, so you normally don't need to specify that.

Also:

`RSAAuthentication` is for SSHv1 which was broken decades ago and should never be used and is disabled by default in all OpenSSH versions for a long time and removed entirely from server side as of 7.4 although I expect CentOS 6 probably does not have that recent a version.

`PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` (plus `authorized_keys2` which is a relic and no longer used) are the defaults so you don't actually need to uncomment them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I'm not 100% if IdentitiesOnly=yes is enabled... I can not see that within my sshd_config file, unless that is an option associated with the creation of the key pair.  If so, I did not use that when creating the pair.  I tried to move the public key to ~/.ssh/, currently sitting beside the authorized_keys file I created earlier and i'm still stuck.  I do have passwords enabled, I'm just trying to do both certificate based authentication and password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly disable password authentication on the server if you only want to allow public/private keys. In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change or add the setting:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I also like to explicitly disable all other types of authentication that I don't use, like Kerberos and GSSAPI.